# Detect long press on UIButton in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIButton` in my Custom `UITableViewCell`. I am working on some control events on that button in the `UITableViewCell` by the following code. This is taken from `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
    cell.gestureButton.tag = indexPath.row ;

    [cell.gestureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellLongPressed:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
    lpgr.delegate = self ;
    [cell.gestureButton addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

I am testing this on iOS 7 Simulator. My problem is , for the first event when `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is executed , I can see the result and my cellTapped method is called properly.

But in the second case where I have assigned a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on my button , I can't see the result in simulator and `cellLongPressed:` method is never called. As far I understand, my code is ok. So, I would like to know , where's the problem ? Is there any problem with my code or Simulator doesn't support this feature ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you checked that `cell.gestureButton` points to the correct UIButton?

Comment: If NOT then Tap shouldn't work.

Comment: Right, right.  I'm betting `lpgr` is conflicting with one of UITableView's gesture recognizers.  Have you tried implementing `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`'s delegate methods?  You may need to set up a failure dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your hint gives me some clues about this. My TableViewCell extends SWTableViewCell that reveals menu on Left or Right Swipe. There's no other GestureRecongnizers here. I'll implement delegate method to check it as you said. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah.  You'll probably need to return `YES` in `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` for this case.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I have managed to solve my problem. Everything is fine now. Please post an answer , I'll accept it as solution. Thank you very much...@Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting `lpgr` is conflicting with another gesture recognizer. Have you tried implementing UILongPressGestureRecognizer's delegate methods? You may need to set up a failure dependency.  Specifically, you'll probably need to return `YES` in `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `cellLongPressed` is declared as following.

```
- (void)cellLongPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
   NSLog(@"cellLongPressed in action");
}
```

**Or if its declared as following:**

```
- (void)cellLongPressed {
   NSLog(@"cellLongPressed in action");
}
```

Please change your gesture initializer to following:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellLongPressed)];
```

Note there is no "**:**" at the end of `cellLongPressed` selector name.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Can you try commenting out this line: `lpgr.delegate = self ;`

Comment: Please can you copy your `cellLongPressed` function in the question too? Just wanna quickly try it here locally.

Comment: I commented out every code inside the method , Just printed a log to check if it's called or not.

Comment: You have helped me partially , my problem was due to multiple gesture recongnizers.Thanks for your help and an upvote for you.